# How to use Alt Codes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I need to build a string which contains Alt Codes, specifically Alt-16 (Arrow symbol).  I have a line of text (aka a string).  I append a Carriage return, then want an ARROW symbol and the new line of text.  This line will then be passed to PPT.  If I manually go into PPT, into a text box, I can hit Alt+16, and get the arrow symbol.  This is what I programatically want to do.
Alt symbols found [here](https://www.alt-codes.net/).

Here is what I am trying, but it gives me a totally different symbol.

```
line := line + #13  + Chr(VK_MENU) + #16 + NewLine;
```

How do I build a string with ALT Codes as part of the string?

Comment: Do you want to use alt codes to type, or do you want to insert an arrow symbol into a Delphi string? Because the way to do the latter does not involve doing the former.

Comment: The arrow code is represented by Alt+16.  I will be placing a string into a text box within PPT.  I need the string to contain the arrow character, aka Alt+16.  In effect, I have a LINE, and then I say PPT.TextBox.text := Line.  Does that make sense?  The ppt part is working.  I just need to embed the Alt+16 in the middle of the string.

Comment: OK. I guess you are set on implementing your solution. Good luck.

Comment: I am open to another approach, just I don't know what it would be.  I am setting the text property (of a powerpoint element), and I need an arrow symbol as part of the text...  If there is another way, i am delighted to try it.

Comment: I think what David is trying to say, is that Alt+Nr is just a way to input characters, but the character itself is not called an Alt-character, and there are other ways to input them. You could try to look up your character in the character map (Windows program), or on a website like `https://unicode-table.com/en/`. Depending on your Delphi version, you can just paste the character in your source code, or use the [`Chr` function](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Chr) to convert a numeric value to a character.

Comment: Then ask about that, and don't insist on alt codes. It's a really common problem here, known as an XY question. Google that.

Comment: [Windows Character Map (charmap.exe)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map_(Windows)) shows the uncode code point of the character, as well as the Alt-code (Alt-keystroke), if available. As you'll notice, these values are not the same. The Alt-code is only for direct typing in. You can't just add 'Alt' plus a number to a string. Btw, please tell us your Delphi-version.

Comment: `Chr(VK_MENU)` isn't what you think it is, I'm afraid. `VK_MENU` is a key code, not a letter you can convert using `Chr`. The `Alt` key is a modifier key, which means a direct conversion to a character isn't going to give you the results you expect.

Comment: Try [Decode/Encode Unicode text](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) or #$25BA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that those characters are not called Alt-codes or Alt-characters. The Alt-codes are just a way to type some special character, but they can't be used as such in a string.

You can just type in that character using the Alt-code, or copy it from the alt codes website. You can use the character as-is in the string. The code below would work fine:

```
// Show it
ShowMessage('►'); 
// Or use it in your string:
line := line + #13  + '►' + NewLine;
```

Comment: That is what I needed.  I was trying to overly complicate things.  Thanks.  It worked perfectly.